# I need connection to an Access Database from a mysql stored procedure to update tables i already create in mysql db

Tags: mysql, ms-access-2010, etl

The access database is on server in folder.  I need to create a stored procedure to connect to the access database and update the table data.  It can be truncate then an insert.  It is connecting via stored procedure to the access database i cannot figure out.  It has to be done via a job on a schedule.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't do that. But what you could do instead is re-configure the Access so it uses MySQL as a backend, so then if you open a table / view in Access it just reads the data direct from MySQL on-demand. That's a much more common scenario which you can read about online.

Comment: This is used all day by credit dept.  It can't be done that way.  I'm trying to get SSIS to connect to mysql but that is giving me fits as well.  I installed the connector mentioned on blog and that did not work either.  That is another question and i understand only one is allowed.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: You may connect TO mysql FROM Access Database (create linked table in it, for example) or use some third intermediate software. If you need to perform the updating periodically (for example, daily) then you may create according subroutine in Access DB and schedule its execution.

Comment: `It can't be done that way`...why not, exactly? Just the fact that the database is used by someone isn't a reason. Make a copy, and give it a try.

Comment: Another option is to use another programming language to extract the data from mysql and then insert it into Access. That program could be run on a schedule easily (using cron / Scheduled Tasks as per your O/S).

Comment: `giving me fits`...isn't an error message or problem statement. If you have a genuine issue with that attempt you could ask a (separate) question about it, giving specific details of the issue, and someone might be able to fix it. Although I'd argue that involving a SQL Server component in a task which has nothing to do with SQL Server probably isn't a good architectural decision anyway.

Comment: So the data is coming from Access into mysql.  Not the other way around.  the comment from Akina...If you need to perform the updating periodically (for example, daily) then you may create according subroutine in Access DB and schedule its execution..  DO i research that to look up the how to do that as it has been over 10 years since i did anything in Access?

Comment: `The data is coming from Access into mysql`...ok but `I need to create a stored procedure to connect to the access database and update the table data`...is what you wrote, so forgive us for thinking it was the other way round. Anyway, you can just do what I said and write a program, except it'll just extract from Access and write to MySQL instead. You _could_ though still use the linked tables idea because then changes in Access could be immediately saved in MySQL (i.e. basically MySQL becomes the backend of the app). It depends if any transformation is required first, that wasn't clear either

Comment: My apologies.  Linked tables i will ask boss but i don't think that is an option.  Thank you all for the insight.

Comment: No problem. A simple C# program would solve this pretty easily though, just SELECT from Access and INSERT to MySQL. All the libraries you need to connect are available easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL (the Sun- then Oracle- owned product) lacks the plumbing to connect to external tables unless they're on other MySQL servers. That is, it only has a [FEDERATED storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html). So, with MySQL you'll have to find some other way to handle your requirement; a [MySQL event](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html) or other stored code cannot hit your Access tables.

MariaDB, the MySQL fork, has a [CONNECT storage engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connect-external-table-types/). It allows the server to hit external tables via ODBC, so you can hit Access with it. MariaDB is almost entirely compatible with MySQL, so maybe you can replace your MySQL server with it. The CONNECT documentation says this, however.

> ...these table types cannot be ranked as stable. Use them with care in production applications.

To me, that warning means **don't do it!**.  Especially with a busy business-critical application (like a credit department might use) you don't want even a little bit of instability. If you truncate a table and then the reload fails, you'll be able to hear users yelling from the next county.

Your requirement is, I believe, to extract the contents of one (or more) Access tables and import them into a MySQL table. That kind of operation is called extract-transform-load [etl](/questions/tagged/etl).  It seems you use SSIS for the purpose. That should work, because SSIS can connect to Access (of course) and to MySQL via the [Connector/net](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/) or [Connector/ODBC](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/) drivers.

But, scheduled SSIS packages get run from SQL Server database servers. You didn't say you have one of those at your disposal.  If your org does have a production SQL Server instance, you can put your Access - to - MySQL package into it.

Otherwise you will have to figure out a way to run your scheduled [etl](/questions/tagged/etl) job without relying on a database job (or [event](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-event.html), as they're called in the MySQL world). For that you'll use the Task Scheduler on Windows, or a cronjob on a UNIX-derived OS like Linux or FreeBSD.

I bet you can do this work reliably from a Windows PowerShell script or a Linux shell script.